# Null Vs Option in F#

Tags: f#, types

I have a problem understanding co-existence of "null" and Option in F#. In a book I have read that null value is not a proper value in F# because this way F# eliminates the excessive null checking. But it still allows null-initialized references in F#. In other words, you can have null values but you don't have the weapons to defend yourself with. Why not completely replace nulls with Options. Is it because of compatibility issues with .NET libraries or languages that it's still there? If yes can you give an example that shows why it can't be replaced by Option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

F# avoids the use of `null` when possible, but it lives in the .NET eco-system, so it cannot avoid it completely. In a perfect world, there would be no `null` values, but you just sometimes need them.

For example, you may need to call .NET method with `null` as an argument and you may need to check whether a result of .NET method call was `null`.

The way F# deals with this is:

- **Null** is used when working with types that come from .NET (When you have a value or argument of type declared in .NET, you can use `null` as a value of that type; you can test if it equals `null`)
- **Option** is needed when working with F# types, because values of types declared in F# cannot be `null` (And compiler prohibits using `null` as a value of these types).

  In F# programming, you'll probably use option when working with .NET types as well (if you have control over how their values are created). You'll just never create `null` value and then use option to have a guarantee that you'll always handle missing values correctly.

This is really the only option. If you wanted to view all types as options implicitly when accessing .NET API, pretty much every method would look like:

```
option<Control> GetNextChild(option<Form> form, option<Control> current);
```

...programming with API like this would be quite painful.

Comment: @amirmonshi: Added some more info.

Comment: @Tomas Thanks for the example:) gave it +1

Comment: @Tomas but honestly other than the ugly looks of option<_> API, I prefer it since I like to work with a unified concept. That's personal I guess

Comment: @amirmonshi: I think F# would never become so popular if it didn't take pragmatic approach (that's why there is no Haskell for .NET). I also like unified concepts and clarity - except, the wild world out there isn't like that.... (and it isn't quite clear if it _can be_)

Comment: @amirmonshi / @Tomas - I think another reason F# was not designed to view all references as types options implicitly when accessing the .NET API is because a lot of the time that would actually misrepresent the set of valid values a method could receive or return. Which of course is the problem with nulls in the first place. What might be nice, is if someone would start a project to wrap a lot of the .NET API with an F# friendly interface which would use options only when specified by a method's verbal contract.

Comment: @Stephen: Yes, that would be nice. I think it could actually use .NET CodeContracts (at least for BCL) that often specify whether a method can take or return `null` or not.

Comment: @Stephen: you would use such a thing?

Comment: @Robert - I believe so, my wish would be for it to align with the .NET API as much as possible for familiarity (so fancy stuff like EDSLs can be saved for other projects). But there may be other F# features to play to besides option types (units of measure come to mind, though I've never explored them so I'm not sure whether they have any place they can be worked in. Or even just using F# functions and modules instead of otherwise extending/overloading classes/members).